# how to use RC6 in php5?

Tags: php, encryption, php-5.3, mcrypt

I need to use RC6 cipher for my project. But, because the installed mcrypt library in my server is mcrypt version 2.5.8, so it's not support for RC6 cipher. As wrote in http://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.ciphers.php, RC6 128 bit cipher only supported by libmcrypt 2.2.x and 2.4.x. Below is the decription that was wrote on that site:

```
MCRYPT_RC6 (libmcrypt > 2.4.x only)

MCRYPT_RC6_128 (libmcrypt 2.2.x only)

MCRYPT_RC6_192 (libmcrypt 2.2.x only)

MCRYPT_RC6_256 (libmcrypt 2.2.x only)
```

I really need to use RC6 cipher for my project. I have try to find how to install the mcrypt library version 2.2.x or 2.4.x, but i can't find it. I used PHP 5.3.2 and this is the output of `php -v` :

> PHP 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.19 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Mar 11 2013 15:23:48) 
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies

Answer (score 0):

You can download the latest version of MyCrypt here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mcrypt/files/latest/download

Comment: Well i'm sorry, i've installed mcrypt 2.6.8 from the link you give, but i still can't use it for my php script. The version of libmcrypt that was installed in my apache server (info.php) is still version 2.5.8, and it's not support RC6 cipher. Can you give me another suggestion?? Thank you...